# BigQuery insert into a partitioned table from an existing table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have to tables with the same schema `tab1` and `tab1_partitioned` where the latter is partitioned by day.

I am trying to insert data into the partitioned table with the following command:

```
bq query --allow_large_results --replace --noflatten_results --destination_table 'advertiser.development_partitioned$20160101' 'select * from advertiser.development where ymd = 20160101';
```

but I get the following error:

```
BigQuery error in query operation: Error processing job 'total-handler-133811:bqjob_r78379ac2513cb515_000001553afb7196_1': Provided Schema does not match Table
```

Both have exactly the same schema and I really don't understand why I am getting that error. Can someone shed some light on my issue?

In fact, I would prefer If BigQuery supported the dynamic partitioning insert that is supported in Hive, but some days of search seem to point that is not possible :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is due to how we treat write dispositions when using them with table partitions.

You should be able to append to the partition using a WRITE_APPEND disposition to get the query to go through.

```
bq query --allow_large_results --append_table --noflatten_results --destination_table 'advertiser.development_partitioned$20160101' 'select * from advertiser.development where ymd = 20160101';
```

There are some complications to making it work with --replace, but we are looking into improved schema support for table partitions at this time.

Please let me know if this doesn't work for you. Thanks!

To answer the other part of your question about dynamic partitioning - we do plan to support richer flavors of partitioning and we believe that they will handle the majority of use cases.

Comment: an extra point regarding the dynamic partitioning: what's the best way to insert existing data into a partitioned bigquery table? Our existing table in Hadoop contains tons of data and is already partitioned

Comment: If you have data in existing bigquery date sharded tables, you can copy it into the partitioned table using the bq cp command.

If you have data outside bigquery, you can load it into BigQuery tables using load job that writes to a table partition (example: table$20160615) as destination. This would ensure data ends up in the partition of your choice.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#restating_data_in_a_partition

Comment: That's what I am doing atm. I thought there was an easier option. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, I don't think it was always so, but there is now a way to copy data from non-partitioned to partitioned tables in bigquery just using DML from the bigquery UI.  For example, if you have a date string in your origin table, of the form YYYY-MM-DD, you could run this to move the data to a partitioned table ...

```
create table my_dataset.my_table (sesh STRING, prod STRING) partition by DATE(_PARTITIONTIME);

insert into my_dataset.my_table (_PARTITIONTIME, sesh, prod) select CAST(PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',  mydatestr) as TIMESTAMP), sesh, prod from my_dataset.my_orig_table;
```